# Android pre onPause notification

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, 2d-games

I am porting an existing game from ios to android using cocos2dx. When the app is paused, eg by clicking the "lock" button on the device, the App is pausing/sleeping just as it should. But when the device is re-activated, and my app shows up again, it freezes for a couple of seconds. What I would like to do, is to show an ingame modal message telling the user that he/she should wait a sec until the game returns from freeze mode. But I simply can make this work.

I have tried to show the message, on "onPause" and on "onResume" but the message is not shown until the freeze mode is over, and I would like it to be shown the moment the app reappears.

How can I make this work?

on Ios it is possible to be notified before the app goes to the background.. "applicationWillResignActive" and I cannot find anything like this on android. Does any notification/delegate function like "pre-onPause" exist on Android?

Any idees are appreciated.

Best

Comment: What's the problem with showing a dialog in onPause() before the super.onPause() call?

Comment: what do you mean by freez? are you doint some reinitializations in onResume?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a BroadcastReceiver that listens for SSCREEN_OFF intent and shows your dialog when that happens, that way it will still be present when the screen comes back on.

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    /**
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(Context,Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //Put your Dialog showing code here
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside your activity you can instantiate and register your receiver like this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is not fired/called until after onPause, and I need something that is called just before onPause is called.

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x project Inside the AppDelegate class there is function applicationDidEnterBackground() where its stop animation thats what the freeze is all about then AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() is the function where the animation starts again which takes time when your app reappears

so put dialogue box or say Pause Screen in applicationDidEnterBackground() and then do the way you want

There can be another way which I am using but it needs JNI calls 
What I have done is I have made JNI calls from android to cocos2d-x .. As I needed everything BroadcastReceiver , Battery Indicator etc ...

SO whenever these things happen I give a JNI call from my onPause method which then comes up with pauseScene in cocos2d-x

Comment: Thanks. When I tell the message box to show, when applicationDidEnterBackground() - or when onPause, it is still not shown untill the app returns from freeze mode. I assume the ccdirector does not update/draw until it returns from Freeze (after onResume).

Comment: @tomas : I guess it should work ..yah if its heavy process ccdirector takes time to update ... after coming from resume .. but you calling ur message box in DidEnterBackground .. see to it that u call it before stopAnimation() ..... so that as soon as it goes in background nd till ccdirector stops all render nd animation you will get that message box and after coming from foreground u can resume d same